# How can we filter a query that depends on a parameter that the user chooses?

Tags: sql-server, filter, parameters, conditional-statements, birt

I'm trying to filter my query depends on what the user selected in period (month or year)
I retrieve the parameter through BIRT.

My query is :

```
SELECT DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE Year(DATE) = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND Month(DATE) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

My result is :

```
DATE
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-01
2017-02-02
```

What I'm trying to do is : if the user select year, i put the last condition in comment, the result should be :

```
DATE
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-02-14
2017-01-25
2017-01-26
2017-02-01
2017-02-02
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
2017-01-20
```

I tried with the CASE like :

```
CASE WHEN USER_PARAM = 'month' then Month(DATE) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) END
```

Obviously, this is not good,
I tried with OR/AND like :

```
Year(DATE) = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    OR ('USER_PARAM' = 'MONTH' AND Month(DATE) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

If `'USER_PARAM' = 'MONTH'` is true -> This is not working because I have all the years (not the current one)

```
Year(DATE) = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    AND ('USER_PARAM' = 'MONTH' AND Month(DATE) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

If `'USER_PARAM' = 'MONTH'` is false-> This is not working because I don't have any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just inverted your condition.
Replace 'MONTH' by 'YEAR' and change the 'AND' with a 'OR' and you are good to go.

```
Year(DATE) = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
AND ('USER_PARAM' = 'YEAR' OR Month(DATE) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I was block on it... close but blocked

Answer (score 1):

The best way to work with user parameters that are optional is (I believe) to allow null to be a wild card or the default.

So if you have a parameter @month that can be null then the following will work

```
WHERE MONTH(DATE) = COALESCE(@month,MONTH(DATE))
```

With this statement if the @month is null then everything matches otherwise it filters

So if you want only the current month in the default you can use

```
WHERE MONTH(DATE) = COALESCE(@month,MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

The final where statement will look like this:

```
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = COALESCE(@year,YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
  AND MONTH(DATE) = COALESCE(@month,MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My parameter is not optional : it can have the value 'month' or 'year' but not null or empty. It's mandatory. 

What is the best solution? I understand AXMIM answer because I was on the same way

Comment: @FannyV -- if it was me I would use the query above and set year or month to a non null value depending on the indicator since most systems are optimized to do coalesce faster than OR